# Jupyter a PDF usando nbconvert y eliminando líneas de código

Tags: python, jupyter

Tengo un documento Jupyter que quiero exportar a PDF. Me han comentado que lo ideal es usar nbconvert. Ya que quiero eliminar del PDF las líneas de código.

Como documento simoplificado presento el siguiente:

```
print("El valor de x es")
```

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(x)
```

Me gusaría que al exportar al PDf via Latex, no me mostrase ninguna linea de codigo, y que solo me muestre los output (los dos print ejecutados)

Muchas gracias

INFORMACION EXTRA:

Quiero poder suprimir una linea al exportarla a PDF.

Esto es e mi codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto al exportarlo a PDF sin codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero eliminar el OUTPUT:

"b'Skipping line 13: expected 1 fields, saw 3\nSkipping line 17: expected 1
fields, saw 2\nSkipping line 33: expected 1 fields, saw 2\nSkipping line 39:
expected 1 fields, saw 3\nSkipping line 43: expected 1 fields, saw 2\nSkipping
line 62: expected 1 fields, saw 2\nSkipping line 65: expected 1 fields, saw
2\nSkipping line 69: expected 1 fields, saw 2\nSkipping line 73: expected 1
fields, saw 2\nSkipping line 76: expected 1 fields, saw 2\n'
"

Pero que se siga ejecutando en mi programa, solo quiero ocultarlo al exportarlo a PDF con nbconvert

GRACIAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nbconvert` tiene la opción `--no-input` apropiada para generar informes libres de código:

```sh
jupyter nbconvert --to PDF --no-input mynotebook.ipynb
```

Comment: Ese comando se incorpora en el prompt de Anaconda y listo? Como fijo la ubicación donde exportar el documento?

Comment: Por defecto, `nbconvert` crea el pdf junto al `.ipynb`. Si quieres otro lugar, puedes usar la opción `--output` o `--output-dir`. Revisa la [documentación de nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io).

Comment: Como hago para no mostrar en concreto un output al exportarlo a PDF? Es un output de aviso, pero que me aparece en el PDF. Adjunto foto en la pregunta inicial

Comment: YA HE ACTUALIZADO LA PREGUNTA

Comment: Lo más sencillo es que borres el _ouput_ de esa celda y guardes el _notebook_ antes de convertirlo a pdf.

Comment: como se borra el output de una celda? Porque necesito que se ejecute ese comando en el programa

Comment: Lo que ahora pides ya no tiene mucha relación con la pregunta original. `nbconvert` tiene una completa API que permite controlar todos los aspectos de la conversión, incluyendo [preprocesadores](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/preprocessors.html#nbconvert.preprocessors.TagRemovePreprocessor) para eliminar partes de una celda en concreto. Lamentablemente, nunca he hecho nada parecido y poco puedo ayudarte en esto.